# Linking NPAPI plugin with FFmpeg makes Firefox unable to load the plugin

Tags: c++, firefox, ffmpeg, npapi

I'm using [Zeranoe FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) static libraries in my NPAPI plugin. The plugin compiles and links correctly, but when I try to test it with Firefox (I'm using Nightly version) it seems that Firefox is unable to load the plugin.

If I remove FFmpeg functionality from the plugin, it loads normally.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time an issue like this is due to missing DLL dependencies.  Try opening the DLL in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see what is missing.

Comment: Indeed, it was avcodec and avutils dlls missing. Thank you!